# Purpose of Show command Window

Tags: powershell

I began playing with Power shell Integrated scripting engine ISE. I could not figure out what the purpose of **Show command window** button(I highlighted in with a red box in the figure below) is for even after searching on the net. Can someone kindly point out what it it for or some links?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell_ise is an IDE for powershell. You can work with it easily because have more option than Powershell.exe . i make short introduce for this IDE under the text  : 
[image]

when you press **Show Command Window** button or press **Show Command Add-on** you got window like command plugin in up-right ise window.
parts of it include :

1. Command search : for searching command and select command type
2. Parameter :here you have parameter for contended command and sometimes have multiple tab on it for enter you're command's parameter .
3. Common parameter : common parameter is some parameter that common between many command
4. Execute section : You can run/copy/insert your command in script powershell with it .
5. Script section : you can write you're script here and run it with F5 or play button (green) at the top of IDE
6. Powershell section : you can see result and enter command here directly

now for example if i want to run this command for get information and help about get-command i should enter this:

```
get-help get-command
```

and i can also do it like this example : 
in section (1) type help the command which content help word will appear i select help . after that i go to section (2) i select detailed view and check the detailed checkbox and in name part write get-command .in (4) section i press run button i will get detailed information about get-command .

Answer (score 1):

It will run cmdlet `Show-Command` which in turn [will show you a GUI dialog](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=294016) about Powershell cmdlets. As per `get-help show-command`:

> The Show-Command cmdlet lets you create a Windows PowerShell command in a command window. You can use the features of the command window to run the command or have it return the command to you.

Comment: Thank You it helped. Actually when it was giving an error earlier. Now its working fine.